# how to open multiple model/database in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two model

```
1) Server Model : conneted to remote database which is stored on server

2) Local Host :  connected to my pc database is stored in on pc.
```

I want to query to both database tables simultaneously.
Each time i have to switch between database model.

How to do it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's a traditional limitation of MySQL Workbench. You cannot open 2 models at the same time in a single instance of MySQL Workbench. On some platforms (like Windows) you can however open multiple instances (just be careful when changing settings, connections etc. as they are shared among all instances, last save wins).

On Windows you may have to enable multiple instances first by changing the setting under `Edit > Preferences > Others (tab)`:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do this on a mac, cause in "preferences", can not find it...
I must be blind..

Comment: Multi instance support only exists for Windows - as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @MikeLischke this is no longer true see my answer. :-)

Comment: @KeizerBridge see my answer.

Comment: For years looking for this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

To launch multiple instances of WorkBench thru the Mac `Terminal`

**Mac Version**: OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

**Workbench Version**: Version 6.2.5.0. Build 397 (32bit) ###

On Your Mac;

1. Open `MySQLWorkbench`
2. Open `Terminal`
3. run `ps ax | grep -i workbench` (as stated above by Derek)

   - Remember the location part of the output:

     - ie: `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench`
4. Lastly, run this to open new `Instances` on your mac

> `open -Fna /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench`

- Please modify the path to your mysql from step 3.

Further Explanation: (from the man pages for `open`)

1. `-F` Opens the application "fresh," that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, except for Untitled documents.
2. `-n`  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.
3. `-a` `application`
        Specifies the application to use for opening the file

Answer (score 16):

As Mike Lischke said.

You can allow multiply instances of MySQL Workbench

Edit -> Preferences -> General (tab) -> Others (section) -> check box

Comment: really helped finding the checkbox Mike meant

Comment: FYI - The `Allow Multiple Instances` configuration on MySQL Workbench, exists ONLY for `Windows Machines`.  Does not show up for `Mac/Linux` MySQL preferences.

Comment: `open -n -a MySQLWorkbench.app` in terminal `MAC`

Answer (score 3):

You can launch multiple instances of WorkBench using the Terminal Application.  Open Workbench as normal, then open Terminal.app. Run "ps ax | grep -i workbench", you should see a result like this: "11260   ??  U      2:34.86 /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench -psn_0_1823165". Copy this part, and paste it into Terminal, /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench and hit enter.  That will create another instance.  Open a new terminal tab, and do that as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

On linux I can open two msql workbench instances. The second instance can be opened by running the executable file directly.

Find where the executable file is located by running

```
ps -ef | grep workbench
20084  1989  0 May09 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
20123 20084  0 May09 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/catchsegv /usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin
20125 20123  0 May09 ?        00:13:25 /usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin
26810  1499  0 11:00 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto workbench
```

Then run the executable file as a root user

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
```