# Is it possible to split .sql query script view in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to split .sql query script view in mysql workbench?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
As reported [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70455) this is a requested missing feature.

However, it's possible to do a little fix if you have Windows, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235894/how-to-open-multiple-model-database-in-mysql-workbench):

1. Go to `Edit > Preferences > Others (tab):`
2. Check Allow more than one instance of MySqlWorkbench to run.

[image]

Then you can finally open more tabs on different windows. Like this:

[image]